# How to copy current timecode to clipboard in Final Cut Pro 7?

Tags: final-cut-pro

Is there a quick way to copy the current timecode position of the timeline cursor to the clipboard in FCP 7?

Comment: apart from selecting it in the timecode display and hitting **cmd-c**? Or do you mean on the fly, while it's playing?

Comment: On the fly, or without having to use the mouse.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you're trying to accomplish? If the time code is changing anywhere from 24 to 60 times a second, what does copying it to the clipboard get you?

Comment: Trying to get timecode values out of FCP 7 Into Aegisub, where someone has already created some text objects in FCP7. I need the timings from them in Aegisub, and the only way I've managed to get them in is manually..